# How to initialize Velocity DateTool within spring webapp?

Tags: java, spring, templates, jakarta-mail, velocity

Recently I needed to initialize Velocity's DateTool in order to properly format date in resulting e-mail. Usually you do this with VelocityContext, however, since I was using spring's VelocityEngineFactoryBean configured in xml, I got to figure out - how can you initialize VelocityContext, when using VelocityEngineFactoryBean?

In other words, my setup:

**webmvc-config.xml**

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
  <property name="velocityProperties">
     <value>
        resource.loader=class
        class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
     </value>
  </property>
```

**MailSender.java**

```
public class CustomMailSender {

@Autowired
private VelocityEngine velocityEngine;

private void sendMail(final Object backingObject) {     
    MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
        public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
            MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);

            // Set subject, from, to, ....

            // Set model, which then will be used in velocity's mail template
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            model.put("backingObject", backingObject);
            String text = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "mail_template.vm", model);
            message.setText(text, true);

        }
    };
    this.javaMailSender.send(preparator);
}
```

In **mail_template.vm** you want to use something like:

```
<li>Transfer start date: $date.format('medium_date', $backingObject.creationDate)</li>
```

How to ensure, that DateTool will be properly initialized and used, when parsing template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After few hours of searching it turns out to be quite trivial: just add one more line when initializing model:

```
private void sendMail(final Object backingObject) {     
    MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
        public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
            MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);

            // Set subject, from, to, ....

            // Set model, which then will be used in velocity's mail template
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            model.put("backingObject", backingObject);

            // Add this line in order to initialize DateTool
            model.put("date", new DateTool());

            String text = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, "mail_template.vm", model);
            message.setText(text, true);

        }
    };
    this.javaMailSender.send(preparator);
}
```

After that you can use **$date** inside your template.